# PrimeFaces DataTable list display and selection

Tags: hibernate, jsf-2, primefaces

I would like to ask you for a help because I stuck with following problem. Another thing what I have to say on the start is that I am a pretty new in JSF developing.

I am using JSF, PrimeFaces, Hibernate and PostgreSQL.

Now I am working on registration form for new users. This test aplication consists of four pages. First one contains basic static informations, on second page is form for filling main informations about user, on third page user will choose free term (here is my problem!) and on last one will be recapitulation and button for save of all filled or choosed informations.

**Third page:**

Here is a PrimeFaces DataTable with Radio Checkboxes and single selection. I followed [PrimeFaces show case](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionRadioCheckbox.jsf) and [BalusC's Datatables tutorial](http://balusc.blogspot.de/2006/06/using-datatables.html#GetSelectedDatatableRow). The problem
 is with impossibility display populated list from db. The main problem is with property **private CollectionTerm selectedTerm** where should be stored selected row.

**Error log**:

```
[javax.el.ELException: Error reading 'dataList' on type de.ibmt.upb.model.CollectionTerm] with root cause
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column collection0_.selectedterm does not exist
  Position: 78
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2157)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1886)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:555)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:417)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:302)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor38.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy25.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2031)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1832)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1811)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:899)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:341)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2516)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2502)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2332)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2327)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:490)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:355)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1247)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101)
    at de.ibmt.upb.model.CollectionTerm.loadDataList(CollectionTerm.java:90)
    at de.ibmt.upb.model.CollectionTerm.getDataList(CollectionTerm.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:87)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:67)
    at org.apache.myfaces.el.unified.resolver.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:169)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:183)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:185)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ContextAwareTagValueExpression.getValue(ContextAwareTagValueExpression.java:96)
    at javax.faces.component._DeltaStateHelper.eval(_DeltaStateHelper.java:246)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:2028)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.getValue(DataTable.java:867)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:579)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.setRowModel(UIData.java:409)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.setRowIndex(UIData.java:401)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.encodeEnd(UIData.java:1690)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:63)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:47)
    at org.primefaces.component.fieldset.FieldsetRenderer.encodeContent(FieldsetRenderer.java:90)
    at org.primefaces.component.fieldset.FieldsetRenderer.encodeMarkup(FieldsetRenderer.java:72)
    at org.primefaces.component.fieldset.FieldsetRenderer.encodeEnd(FieldsetRenderer.java:46)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:580)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:762)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:758)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:758)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.renderView(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:1900)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:285)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:115)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:241)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@Entity
@Table(name="COLLECTION_TABLE")
public class CollectionTerm implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private Integer c_id;
    private Date dateCollection;
    private Time timeCollection;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="coll")
    private Collection<UserDetails> userDetails = new ArrayList<UserDetails>();

    @ElementCollection(targetClass=CollectionTerm.class)
    private List<CollectionTerm> dataList;

    private CollectionTerm selectedTerm;

    public CollectionTerm() {

    }

        ///// getters and setters /////

    public List<CollectionTerm> getDataList() {
        if (FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getRenderResponse()) {
                loadDataList();
        }
        return dataList;
    }

    private void loadDataList() {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        dataList = session.createQuery("from CollectionTerm").list();
    }

}
```

JSF:

```
<h:form id="collection">
    <p:fieldset legend="Date and time">
        <p:dataTable id="collection" value="#{coll.dataList}" var="coll" rowKey="#{coll.c_id}" selection="coll.selectedTerm">
            <p:column selectionMode="single" style="width:2%" />  
            <p:column >
                #{coll.timeCollection}
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                #{coll.dateCollection}
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                #{coll.c_id}
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
        <p:commandButton value="Back" action="registrationback" ajax="false" />
        <p:commandButton value="Next" action="recap" ajax="false" />
        <p:commandButton value="Test" action="testcollection" ajax="false" />
     </p:fieldset>
</h:form>
```

Faces-config:

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>coll</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>de.ibmt.upb.model.CollectionTerm</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>

<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>userService</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>de.ibmt.upb.model.UserDetails</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    <managed-property>
        <property-name>term</property-name>
        <value>#{term}</value>
    </managed-property>
    <managed-property> 
        <property-name>coll</property-name>
        <value>#{coll}</value>
    </managed-property>  
</managed-bean>
```

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks for any replies or recommendations!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: ERROR: column collection0_.selectedterm does not exist

That's your root cause. You need to address that mapping/DB error first. Then

1. As a matter of best practice and useability, don't combine your JPA entity and JSF Managed Bean. That means `@ManagedBean` and `@Entity` should not be declared on the same POJO Your bean should either be a model or a controller, not both.
2. Use either the `@ManagedBean` annotation or the *faces-config.xml* file, not both. Although the file will take precedence (I believe) over the annotations, it'll eventually cause confusion

Comment: Thank you for your help. Sorry for late feedback. I devided previous bean into two separated and it is now much clearer. But I have another problem. With setting for PrimeFaces datatable with radio checkbox, returns to me this error: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: **Property 'c_id' not found on type java.lang.String** Now, I really don't know what I should change. But probably it is hard to say only from this error message.

Comment: @PrincAm, you'll need to post another whole question to get a definitive answer, but my best guess is that you're having JSF conversion related problems

Answer (score 0):

The Entity bean should be a mere reflection of your table. Each column should be mapped to the column name. Once you construct the Entity bean you could invoke it and get the desired result.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="COLLECTION_TABLE")
public class CollectionTerm implements Serializable {
..
..
..
@Id
        @Column(name = "c_id")
        private Integer c_id;
        @Column(name = "date")
        private Date dateCollection;
        @Column(name = "time")
        private Time timeCollection;
...
..

}
```

Something like above to match your underlying table structure. This should give you a head start.

Comment: Thanks for explanation and recommendation!